# Creating user in Firebase gives me an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm following a [Savvy Apps](https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase) tutorial in order to learn Vue.js. This tutorial uses Firebase with Firestore. Since Firestore is in Beta (as the tutorial says), changes might happen - and I think that might be the case here.

In any case, I'm trying to sign up a new user. I fill out the form and click 'Sign up' and I get this error message:

> Error: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type string, but it was: undefined

But looking in Firebase, I see that the user has been created. So why do I get this error message? What is the first argument?

The code for signup looks like this:

```
  signup() {
    this.performingRequest = true;
    fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(user => {
      this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user);
      // create user obj
      fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
        name: this.signupForm.name,
        title: this.signupForm.title
      }).then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile');
        this.performingRequest = false;
        this.$router.push('/dashboard')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.performingRequest = false;
        this.errorMsg = err.message
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.performingRequest = false;
      this.errorMsg = err.message
    })
  },
```

Let me know if you need more code - this is the first time I'm testing Vue.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) returns a `Promise` containing a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential).  `UserCredential` has a property `user` for the [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object.

You need to make the appropriate changes to your code to correctly access the UID:

```
  signup() {
    this.performingRequest = true;
    fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password)
    .then(credential=> {  // CHANGED
      this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', credential.user);  // CHANGED
      // create user obj
      fb.usersCollection.doc(credential.user.uid).set({  //CHANGED
        name: this.signupForm.name,
        title: this.signupForm.title
      }).then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile');
        this.performingRequest = false;
        this.$router.push('/dashboard')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.performingRequest = false;
        this.errorMsg = err.message
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.performingRequest = false;
      this.errorMsg = err.message
    })
  },
```

Comment: Good catch Bob!

Comment: Hmm, I just get `credential is not defined`

Comment: Can't say what the problem is without seeing your revised code. Did you make the change for `.then(credential=>...` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't see the first definition of 'credential'. Now it worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: Interesting, my signUp() works without changing it to credential, but I have to use credential for login()

Comment: this saved me! I was on the exact same course, and got stuck later on, due to this. Thanks!