# Firebase: can't write Username + Title to DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, nosql

I am following this guide:
https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase

My login view:

[image: Login view]

I am trying to get the `signupForm.name` and `signupForm.title` into the database. However, as far as I can see, it is not working, beacause I am getting the "undefined" in another file & also, I can not see it anywhere in the backend. All i see is this:

[image: Authentication Tab]

While the "Database" remains completely empty.

[image: Database Tab]

My suspicion is, that this part of the tutorial may be outdated, and thus not working as intended. I am new to this.

login.vue **simplified**:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name" class="label">Name</label>
    <input v-model.trim="signupForm.name" type="text" placeholder="Savvy Apps" id="name" class="input" />
    (...)
</div>

<script>
(...)
const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
  export default {
  (...)
  methods: {
  (...)
    signup() {
        this.performingRequest = true
        fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(user => {
           this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
            // create user obj
            fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
                name: this.signupForm.name,
                title: this.signupForm.title
            }).then(() => {
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.$router.push('/dashboard')
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                this.performingRequest = false
                this.errorMsg = err.message
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            this.performingRequest = false
            this.errorMsg = err.message
        })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is "signupForm.name" and "signupForm.title" defined in the data object?
Does an error shows in the console?

Comment: Just found the exact solution by coincidence! But thanks for your effort!

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583290/creating-user-in-firebase-gives-me-an-error

Comment: First, you need to set up the rules for your database. or just for test reason add .read and .write = true. Then you need to just pass String to your user if you have multiple parameters in the user class you need to add all oh them separately for example ["username" = user.name, "phone" = user.phone] and so on.
Also, if it's possible for you to upload any kind of information about the error or send actual error here can help more.